# React Component not re-rendering when prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components - layout, navigation, and room dropdown. Layout gets a property 'lobbyCode' from a database and sets it to a state, then passes it as a prop to Navigation. Navigation then passes this prop as a prop to RoomDropdown, however the room dropdown component does not re-render when the lobbyCode state is changed in layout. Navigation seems to handle the state change fine and re-renders correctly, so I'm not sure what's happening.

**Layout:**

```
const { user, isAuthenticated, isLoading } = useAuth0();
const [lobbyCode, setLobbyCode] = useState("");

return (
    <div>
       <Navigation GetUser={GetUser} GetPlayers={GetPlayers} lobbyCode={lobbyCode} user={user} 
       isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} isLoading={isLoading} />
    </div>
  )

useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      GetUser(user.email).then(result => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          setLobbyCode(result[0].lobby);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [user]);
```

**Navigation:**

```
<RoomDropdown lobbyCode={props.lobbyCode} GetUser={props.GetUser} GetPlayers={props.GetPlayers} user={props.user} />
```

**RoomDropdown**

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.lobbyCode);
}, [props.lobbyCode]);
```

The result is that the room dropdown will just print undefined and never update, even once the lobby code is loaded.

Comment: `lobbyCode` is surely an empty string in your example, rather than `undefined`. In any case, it never updates because you never call `setLobbyCode`, or pass it to any other component that might call it. I appreciate you boiling everything down to the minimum essentials to reproduce the problem, but it looks like you've left off some code which is important to understanding your problem!

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks for the response. I did leave out a bit of code as it introduces more functions that are mostly irrelevent to this issue, but I'll add on the code as an edit that calls setLobbyCode. And yes you are correct, I meant to say that it is an empty string

Comment: thanks. I agree with this updated code then it looks like you should see the new `lobbyCode` value in the `RoomDropdown` component when it changes in the parent. So my next question is: are you sure that it is actually being changed? Try logging its value inside each of the 3 components in the tree - or, if you have React developer tools installed, look at its value there. Without knowing the results of that I'm just guessing wildly - although my suspicion is that it's probably not in fact updating, even in the parent component.

Comment: It's definitely updating in both the parent component and in `Navigation`, as I am using an effect hook to log `lobbyCode` inside of `Navigation` when it changes. It's only `RoomDropdown` that isn't reflecting the state's change.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yM8eUSZ Here you can see the props for each component. Even more confusingly, all the other props are being updated correctly.

Comment: thanks - well I must admit I'm baffled so far. I even though you might have a typo in the name of the prop which means it's not passing the correct one down - but I can't see one (and if there was, you would have `undefined` rather than an empty string anyway!). Do you have a CodeSandbox (or similar site) demo that can show the issue, so I can see it there and nteract with it myself?

Comment: I don't sorry, it's all being done locally. Is there a way to export the project from vscode to a code sandbox?

Comment: Okay after doing a bit of testing, it seems to be linked to the fact that I'm instantiating the component outside of the `return` statement as I'm rendering it conditionally. If I just directly render the component then the prop passes down fine, but that won't be useful for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I fixed it!! Changed the conditional rendering to use if statements as opposed to storing a state variable with the content to be rendered. I guess you can't pass dynamic props by reference inside a state, which makes sense now that I consider it.

Comment: I don't really follow all that, but well done for solving it! Sounds like there was indeed a lot of code that was contributing to the problem that you never shared.